# code don't stop the Refresh

Tags: javascript

I'm learning js now. Testing this code to stop the refresh of the input option, but this isn't working

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".formulario-cadastro").submit(funtion(){
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Assuming your HTML markup supplements your JavaScript, and the jQuery library is included correctly, I think you merely have a typo: `funtion()` => `function()`.

Comment: "stop the refresh of the input option" What? Please ask a colleague, a friend  or someone else to look at your question and ask him/her if he/she understand it? Then edit your question to make he/she understand.

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. I can think of four completely different reasons why this might fail off the top of my head.

Comment: … make that five.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in `function` word. You need to prevent default. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".formulario-cadastro").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: this work. thank you